# Remove digit from MNIST, PyTorch

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, mnist, pytorch-dataloader

I'm experimenting with rotating the MNIST digits. Because a 9 is more or less a rotated 6, I'd like to remove all occurrences from the dataset.

As per [this answer](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-use-one-class-of-number-in-mnist/26276), I tried

```
dataset = datasets.MNIST(root='./data')
idx = dataset.train_labels!=9
dataset.train_labels = dataset.train_labels[idx]
dataset.train_data = dataset.train_data[idx]
```

which fails because the properties of the MNIST class are only readable.

I'd really like to not have to manually iterate through the entire dataset, and create a list of tuples that I feed to my dataloaders. Am I out of luck?

Answer (score 1):

You might proceed as follows, namely by replacing `train_labels` with `targets` and `train_data` with `data`:

```
from torchvision import datasets

dataset = datasets.MNIST(root='data')
idx = dataset.targets!=9
dataset.targets = dataset.targets[idx]
dataset.data = dataset.data[idx]
```

Indeed, as you can see at https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/_modules/torchvision/datasets/mnist.html#MNIST, `train_labels` and `train_data` have eventually been marked as properties and as such they can't be set to some values, while `targets` and `data` have been probably added as public attributes in the meanwhile.

```
@property
def train_labels(self):
    warnings.warn("train_labels has been renamed targets")
    return self.targets

@property
def train_data(self):
    warnings.warn("train_data has been renamed data")
    return self.data
```